# Exclude files/directories from code review requirement

Tags: github, github-codereviews

Our github repo includes a directory containing language translation files. These are generated automatically from a database. Ideally we should find a way to deploy these through some other mechanism than updating them in our github repository, but that's how it's currently done.

We also have an `ads.txt` file that we just update with fixed entries whenever our advertising partner sends us new lines. These don't mean anything to us, we just take what they send us.

So whenever these files are updated, we have to go through the process of creating a pull request and reviewing it. I just do a cursory check that it only contains the appropriate files, and then give a pro forma approval.

Is there any way of marking files like these as not requiring code review, so the engineer can just push and merge the changes, and deploy without bothering another engineer for approval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by Github per default. But Github Actions should be powerful enough to handle that requirement.
Consider the following pipeline, triggered  on each pull request:

- It performs a `git diff` to get the list of all files that have been changed. On a quick glance, [this github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-diff-action) seems to do that
- If only files at a specific path or name have been changed, it approves the pull request. Look [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/approve-pull-request) for an example action

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You could [create a custom role](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-18-bypass-branch-protections-with-a-new-permission/) and [assign it to a specific user](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/managing-custom-repository-roles-for-an-organization) to a specify user.

If your GitHub Actions identifies as that user, it should then be able to push directly to a protected branch.

Comment: How do we make this only apply to specific files or directories in the repo?

Comment: From what I can see, this apply to repositories only. If you can isolate a directory in its own repository (and reference it as a submodule in the main repository), that would apply.